# Always sort NULL as empty string or 0

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I am trying to make all queries in our system `ORDER BY` with `NULL` and empty strings being equal (only in ORDER BY). I solved this by adding `IFNULL(field, "")` to all `GROUP BY` fields.

Now the problem is that if a field type is numeric, then the field is converted to a `String` which will sort 100 before 20 because its alphabetical, not by number. If I change "" to 0, it casts everything to an int and that makes the sorting by on `varchar` fields go wrong.

Is there a universal way that I can say "if it is NULL, treat it as an empty string on ORDER BY"? Or maybe, "if the field type is a string, use this function"? In this simple example i could switch the secondary value depending on the field but I am looking for a more global solution.

Example table data:

```
---------------
|id|person|age|
|1 |Zzz   |100|
|2 |      |0  |
|3 |NULL  |2  |
|4 |      |2  |
---------------
```

Some examples:

```
//correct results
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY IFNULL(`person`, ""), id ASC;
//null and empty strings not sorted properly
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY IFNULL(`person`, 0), id ASC;

//correct results
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY IFNULL(`age`, 0), id ASC;
//100 is turned to a string and therefor appears above 2
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY IFNULL(`age`, ""), id ASC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if anyone happens upon this post, it seams the best way to go about this is to use `NULLIF` instead of `IFNULL` to convert all NULL values to empty strings.

This will only work when you are dealing with strings and not NULL numbers though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is no magic option to do what you want.

However, you might consider using `DEFAULT` values in your `CREATE TABLE` statements, so avoid `NULL` values -- just set the default to `0` or `''` depending on the data type.